# c++ drops udp packets with recvmmsg

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I am developing an c++ program which consumes a stream of UDP data from an FPGA over ethernet.  There is no hub or router between the FPGA and my ethernet card.  The data is 10446 pps with a rate of 125350.0 kbps.

My c++ app uses a dedicated thread and recvmmsg to empty the data.  Each packet has a sequence number as the first 4 bytes, followed by 1468 bytes of stream data.  I am using recvmmsg and i have tried `VLEN` (10,100) and combinations of `MSG_WAITFORONE`, `MSG_DONTWAIT`, `0` for flags.

The symptoms I am seeing are this:

- Before the program starts, the stream is running at a fixed speed.
- When the program boots, I have a short initial period where the return value of `recvmmsg` is the same as `VLEN`.  If i understand correctly, this is the draining of the Linux kernel buffer.
- After this, I always get a value of `1` for the return value of `recvmmsg`
- If I cause small load on the system (resizing a gui window for instance). I see a drop of UDP packets, as indicated by missing sequence numbers.  (not reordered, just missing).
- During/after a drop, I do not get a larger return value for `recvmmsg`
- Wireshark/tcpdump do not show any missing data, all sequence numbers are present.

If i watch the output of `netstat -suna`, I see increases of the value of  `RcvbufErrors:`.

If I watch the output of `ifconfig` I do not see any dropped packets (`RX packets:602492703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0`).

These are my questions:

- Why do I never get more than one packet from `recvmmsg` during a drop condition?
- Why is wireshark able to capture the packets, but my c++ cannot?
- What tools can I use to get a better understanding of why I am dropping?

I have tried adjusting the following tunables:

- `sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=10000`
- `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=9926214400`

Please do not suggest that I should switch to TCP.  This is not an option for this particular application.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer your detailed questions, but you could try increasing the size of the receive buffer with `setsockopt ( ... SO_RCVBUF ... )`;

Comment: Thanks Paul Sanders! This worked for me. If you copy this into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the size of the receive buffer for the receiving socket should solve this:

```
setsockopt (fd, IPPROTO_UDP, SO_RCVBUF, desired_receive_buffer_size);
```

Documentation [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt).

Comment: The reason Wireshark shows it is that it sees it first, before it traverses the stack to the UDP layer, which drops it if the buffer is full.